# Titanium iphone with Facebook connect to rails devise app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, devise, titanium

I'm developing an iPhone app with Titanium which is doing API calls to a Rails3 app with Devise/Omniauth.

And I just can't seem to get how to FB Connect in the app and then be able to auth my API calls.
There's is [a start here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809490/devise-omniauth-and-iphone-android-app) but it means that the user has to:

1. FB Connect in the app
2. Send the result to the rails app to get a devise token
3. Ask for what it needs to using that token

Is there any way to directly use the result of Step 1 and get rid of Step 2?

Super thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can make the facebook connect calls directly from the titanium application.

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/td/280+Integrating+Contacts+&+Social+APIs

Comment: Thank you Aaron, but once the Titanium app is facebook connected how do I authenticate API calls on my own rails3 app?

Comment: i guess i am confused by your architecture, the user has authorized the mobile application to access there facebook account, not the server?

Comment: Well, maybe I'm completely off topic :)
Or I guess that there is something that must be so simple that I can't see it!
But it's super simple to have a FB Connect on a rails app, it's super simple to have a FB Connect on an iPhone app.
But can't find a great way to have the login via FB on the iPhone app and to get API calls to the rails app done in a nice way.
Except going through the process described in the linked SO question.