# Rails Devise OmniAuth Facebook Login from iOS

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, omniauth

I've been searching for a solid solution to this problem, and came across [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809490/devise-omniauth-and-iphone-android-app) question which kind of matches my predicament, but not exactly.

Currently I have my iPhone application authenticating with my Rails API via Basic Auth.  It's just your simple, run-of-the-mill devise auth package.  I then followed the instructions to set up omniauth-facebook for devise and got that working on the browser side.

The part I can't figure out how to do is how to send the token received on the iPhone side (via the Facebook iOS SDK) to the server.  I want the server to check the users table to see if that facebook user has signed up, and create an account for him if he hasn't. Then, I was thinking the server would generate a random password and send it back to the client device so that I could keep my same basic authentication strategy.  Is this the proper way to implement single sign on for a web app and iPhone app?  How would one go about modifying the server side packages to support authentication via a token sent from the phone?

Comment: You can send the access token gathered via Facebook iOS SDK to your API and check if token is valid and user is exists or not by calling /me on Facebook API with that token. If the token valid and mail address returned from your fb/me call exists on your API let iOS app login, if token is valid but user doesn't exists, register that user.

Comment: Maybe something in these comments can be useful https://gorails.com/forum/mobile-app-with-devise-facebook-omniauth

Answer (score 4):

You may want to take a look here:

[Open Source: Announcing devise-iOS For Simplified Auth](https://netguru.co/blog/open-source-announcing-devise-ios)

It looks like a relatively painless way to work with Rails / Devise and iOS.  I definitely plan on using it in my next project.

Comment: This is not a solution because inevitably he will need to get it working on Android as well. And the good solution would be cross-mobile platform.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into making your app an Oauth2 provider?

I haven't done this myself, but after some digging it looks like opro and doorkeeper are two possible solutions to the problem.

https://github.com/opro/opro
https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper

looks like opro works pretty well with devise:

```
#inside initializers/opro.rb
Opro.setup do |config|
  config.auth_strategy = :devise
end
```

Definitely interested to see how this turns out for you

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right plan.  We've done exactly this in our app and Web service.

The apps use a REST API, basic authentication over HTTPS, a server-generated password, and all of this is implemented *without* Devise.  There's a method in the controller that all the API controllers inherit from, that is a before_action for all the API methods, and it calls 'authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic'

```
class ApiController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_api
  def authenticate_api
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      # check server-generated password
    end
  end
end
```

So that handles most requests.

We also have a API controller action to register from the device once to get that server-generated password:

```
class UsersController < ApiController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_api, only: [:register_fb]

  def register_fb
    graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(params.require("access_token"))
    profile = graph.get_object("me?fields=email,first_name,last_name")
    # then go on to look up user if already exists, or create
    # ...  return server-generated password
  end
end
```

The Web app, however, all controllers inherit from WebappController and use devise.

Thus we have two passwords on the User object (one for web, one for mobile) and a facebook ID as well as our own User id which is the one we use for authentication.